# maven surefire additionalClasspathElements single test

Tags: maven-2, surefire

I have one main and one test config file which is shared by several maven projects. While testing, I am specifying the classpath to the directory where the test config file is.

This works fine if the whole project is tested/build but it doesn't work while running single tests. The config file is not found in the classpath.

here is the config:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <additionalClasspathElements>
       <element>${project.parent.basedir}/conf/test</element>
    </additionalClasspathElements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

any ideas why surefire ignores the property for running single tests?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<additionalClasspathElements>
  <additionalClasspathElement>${project.parent.basedir}/conf/test</additionalClasspathElement>
</additionalClasspathElements>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the config file in src/test/resources folder and try it .It should automatically be picked up. OR try to put under src/main/resources and use  tag to point to that config file in  the pom.xml of the project .Make use of 2.5 version of maven-surefire plugin.